# Locating (and resolving) conflicting redirect rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to force `non-www` on my Wordpress site. I can get force https working fine but because something, somewhere seems to be forcing `www`, my `non-www` rules are sending it into a redirect loop. I've tried adding the rules before the Wordpress specific rules in the base .htaccess file to no avail. I've even tried removing the Wordpress rules altogether and that didn't work either. If this is a problem unrelated to that base .htaccess, is there a simple way to find the source of a redirect (rule or file) and does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Non-www rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Standard Wordpress Rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you do not post the rules at hand?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed the problem wasn't with the rules I had, but with some other rules - the location of which I'm unsure. Have added the rules in question.

Comment: Well, the other obvious location for rewrite rules is the http servers host configuration. We cannot tell you where your rules come from, sorry.

Comment: Extremely cryptic rules, not good for a robust and maintainable setup...

Comment: Oh, it could also be that wordpress makes that redirection if you have a host name configured in there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite unfamiliar with .htaccess obviously. I got that particular rule from `http://htaccesscheatsheet.com/#force-non-www`but I've tried other similar ones with same result. by `non-www` I mean one which removes 'www' from the beginning of all URL's (where applicable)

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I had tried that, yeah. It didn't help in my particular situation though.

Answer (score 0):

@arkascha was right, in `settings` of wordpress, the url was configured to `www.___`. Still not sure where that rule gets substantiated into actual code but there you go.